# Is it possible to perform audio conversions on Heroku using oggenc and mpg321?

Tags: ruby, heroku

Is it possible to use the audio conversion tools oggenc and mpg321 on Heroku?
If not, are there any ruby gems that can handle this kind of conversion. Much Googling has turned up nothing helpful.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to look at [Heroku buildpacks](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/7/17/buildpacks), and maybe give [ffmpeg-heroku](https://github.com/dzello/ffmpeg-heroku) a try.

FFmpeg appears to have a library for [oggenc](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/oggenc_8c-source.html), and you can appear to install mpg321 on Linux, so it may be doable.

Maybe someone with more experience can provide a better answer than me. At least I've given you a couple things to look at in the meantime!

If you don't mind paying for a 3rd party encoding service, I'd also add that I love Zencoder's service. You may want to see if their [supported formats](http://zencoder.com/en/formats) meet your requirements.